# How to interact with Tables using EclipseLink without using Entity classes?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I don't have Entity classes in my project. My requirement is When I am connecting to DataBase Based on schema I have to Get the all Tables names from that schema.

Here I have a Schema as "companydb" with 5 tables. Below is my code to retrieve total number of tables from particular schema.

Here may be Exception occur by "Query". Query is not well here so what type of query I have to use and how Can I get List of tables.

persiatance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="reports" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reports" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

GetTableList.java

```
@WebServlet("/GetTableList")
public class GetTableList extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEmf()
            .createEntityManager();
    try {

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM companydb.tables");
        List list = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println(list);
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();

        }
        out.print(list);
        System.out.println("Data retrived successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT * FROM companydb], line 1, column 7: unexpected token [*].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(93@[330:16: ( DISTINCT )?])
```

how can I over come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Native query to get List of tables from your schema

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SHOW TABLES FROM companydb");
```